# Помогите разобраться, как поймать ошибку с телеграм-бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

```
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message) {
        try {
            file_get_contents($this->api.$this->access_token . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '
        &parse_mode=html&text=' . urlencode($message));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errorData = $e->getResponseData();
            return $errorData;
        }

    }
```

Пытаюсь разобраться с try и catch, но что-то делаю не так...

Comment: try/catch сработает в том случае, если ты сам вызовешь ошибку throw new Exception() при возврате false функцией file_get_contents() https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php пример 4

Comment: К уже написанному вам другими добавлю - эта функция используется для чтения файла, а не обращений к API, которые могут вернуть что-то еще кроме HTTP 200/404 (поэтому у неё и есть булевый тип возврата - либо есть файл, либо его нет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким образом у вас не получился отловить ошибку, поскольку функция `file_get_contents` возвращает прочтённые данные или false в случае возникновения ошибки. Соответветственно, тут можно проверить на `false`, но текста ошибки не будет.

Возможно, а возврате функции и будет текст ошибки... Попробуйте посмотреть, что приходит `file_get_contents`.

Comment: либо вернуться пустой ответ, всякой бывает.

Comment: @Jean-Claude тут может быть само API вернет JSON, так что можно его просто обработать